# Mac shortcut keys: How to add a generic "About [app]" to keyboard shortcuts?

Tags: macos

I want to add a shortcut to "About" for every software, just like most of them have <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd> for entering preferences.

But this could as well be a question used for many other things, since I want to do it through either Automator, Script or just System Preferences, if possible.

Any hints on how to do this? Please, no third part solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
tell application "System Events"
    try
        set a to name of process 1 where frontmost is true
        tell process a to click menu bar 1's menu bar item 2's menu 1's menu item 1
    end try
end tell
```

The same approach also works for *Undo** and *Redo** in most applications.

[How to assign a shortcut for running an Applescript](https://superuser.com/questions/153890/bind-a-key-to-a-commandline-command-in-mac-os-x/264943#264943)

Comment: Sounds lovely. I'll see if I can use this! :)

Comment: Lri, about your edit, by chance I've tried the exact steps you described there with Automator, but for some reason that's not working - I can't find the service listed either in *Keyboard Services* or any *Application > Services*. I'm trying to find out why.

Comment: All right, I just redid it once again and took care to paste it in the proper place (the first time I've replaced the `on run` part). Now the actual script isn't working. It just does nothing.

Comment: @Cawas Did you try logging out and back in?

Comment: @Lri I have issues with logging out as I always have a lot of things open... Plus I wouldn't think it would be required in this case! But I'll try that soon enough. Thanks again!

Comment: @Lri still not working after a reboot. Starting to investigate now...

Comment: @Cawas Ok, I just fixed a similar issue yesterday with a relogin. (I was trying out ThisService for [Can I use a bash script as a Service in OS X without having to set it up trough automator? - Super User](http://superuser.com/questions/264954/can-i-use-a-bash-script-as-a-service-in-os-x-without-having-to-set-it-up-trough-a/264969#264969)). Another way to update services is apparently `/System/Library/CoreServices/pbs`, but you shouldn't have to do it manually for services in (~)/Library.

Comment: @Lri the service is up even before the reboot. if I press the shortcut several times I can even see the little notification icon in the icon area on the top saying it's running - several of them, for a brief period. It's just the script isn't working for some reason.

Comment: @Lri last thing I could realize is it's not getting inside *tell application "System Events" / try*. I've set automator to display the apple script before running so it's easy to debug - but I just don't know enough apple script to get around this issue easily. Would you know what could be wrong?

Comment: @Cawas Are you sure you selected *Service recieves: [no input]*? It works just fine for me. There's a ~1 second delay before running it though, which doesn't occur with eg FastScripts. So do you really have to wrap it as an Automator service? It would be a lot easier (and probably faster) to just run it directly.

Comment: @Lri yes, I sure selected *[no input]* and the challenge here is without 3rd parties. But I just tried it on another machine (mine at home), simply by copying the workflow from ~/Library/Services, and **it worked**! So it's something weird on that other machine at work, which I have *not even sudo permissions* and thus a lot less crap installed.