# Can I use a bash script as a Service in OS X without having to set it up trough automator?

Tags: macos, bash, script, services

How can I use a bash script as a Service in OS X without having to set it up trough automator? I'd basically like to write a bash script, save it in  ~/Library/Services and then just have it show up in the services menu. Thoughts?

Comment: The `mac` tag is for questions about Mac *hardware*. While the `osx` tag is for *software*. Choose one or the other.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[ThisService](http://wafflesoftware.net/thisservice) is a bit more streamlined than Automator:

[image: thisservice]

---

The built-in script menu can also be used to run shell scripts:

[image: script menu shell scripts]

It can be enabled from *AppleScript Utility — Preferences — Show Script menu in menu bar*. It includes files in ~/Library/Scripts/ and optionally /Library/Scripts/. You can't assign shortcuts though — that's the main reason to use [FastScripts](http://www.red-sweater.com/fastscripts/) instead.

---

Some applictions for just assigning shortcuts: [osx - Bind a key to a commandline command in Mac OS X? - Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/153890/bind-a-key-to-a-commandline-command-in-mac-os-x/264943#264943).

Comment: Do you know whether it's actually different from an Automator service (e.g. performing better), or just a different implementation of the same idea/different GUI? Can it be automated or controlled from command line?

Answer (score 1):

You should consider trying [FastScripts](http://www.red-sweater.com/fastscripts/). It's like OS X's scripts menu done right, including keyboard shortcuts for easy access.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a way to do that directly.  Aside from Automator, you can also use XCode to build an AppleScript wrapper for your script that will work as a Service.

Using the script directly is more problematic.  My understanding is that it needs to be an app bundle, and then it needs specific entries in its `Info.plist` telling the system what service it offers.  The former can be done with [Platypus](http://www.sveinbjorn.org/platypus); for the latter, use the Property List Editor in XCode (or `plutil` and an XML editor if you <strike>hate yourself</strike> like playing with XML directly) to craft an [`NSServices`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/SysServices/Articles/properties.html) key.

This leaves the rather big question of how to invoke it; the Objective-C message created from `NSServices` key `NSMessage` isn't going to be understood directly by a shell, and it looks like Platypus doesn't have a way to receive it either.  I suspect that means writing a custom wrapper in Objective-C.